# IE11 opening Edge from within Word addon

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer, office-js, .net-6.0

## Issue

I am currently facing an issue pertaining to the updates made to Microsoft Edge in which Microsoft Edge will take control of link redirects within Internet Explorer 11. This problem specifically occurs within my Microsoft Office addon for Word with Microsoft Office 2016/2019 (volume licensing) versions.

To explain the problem end to end, I’ll run through the process of how I can replicate it.

Once I open our addon within Microsoft Word, the addon will ensure that the user is currently logged in and should the user not be logged in, my authentication middleware will redirect the user to the login page. The login page will then be presented to the user – still within the addon and not a separate browser window – where the user can enter their credentials and proceed to click on the sign in button.

Once a user clicks on the sign in button, the authentication system will perform a redirect to create tokens and then once more perform a redirect back to the provided return URL. During this stage of the login process I am encountering the issue. The initial redirect after the user has clicked the sign in button causes a Microsoft Edge browser window to open to the redirect URL and once the tab opens up, the login process fails as it’s no longer within the context it was created (in this case within the addon IFrame in Word).

How can Microsoft Office versions still making use of Internet Explorer 11 not be made exempt from Microsoft Edge taking over redirects? Has anyone had this issue or found a solution to it apart from Group Policies?

## Expected Behavior

Once a user clicks on the sign in button, the authentication system should perform a redirect to create tokens and then once more perform a redirect back to the provided return URL. These redirects within IE11 within the Word addon should not cause Edge to take over redirects and should keep opening within the addon in Word.

Comment: Is the login process in a dialog you've opened with `displayDialogAsync` or are you trying to do it in a task pane? Also, since you are on desktop Office, there wouldn't ordinarily be an iFrame involved.

Comment: @RickKirkham This is being done in the task pane and not with displayDialogAsync. Apologies, with IFrame I was referring to task pane.

Comment: I'm trying to get some information internally in Microsoft about your issue. In the meantime, note that if any of your add-ins users will be working with Office on the web (formerly Office Online), you login system will probably not work. Most login providers do not allow their login screen to open in an iFrame and in Office on the web, the task pane IS an iFrame.

Comment: @RickKirkham Thanks for offering to have a look at this. I've been playing with getting around this with group policies but this doesn't always seem to work. Have you found anything on your end that could potentially work?

Comment: Still trying to get some answers.